# Select Top Selling ProductID By Quarter Within Price Group

Tags: sql, sql-server, case, partition

I have this query:

```
WITH product_grouped AS (
    SELECT 
    p.uniqueid, 
    cost, 
    case WHEN cost <= 10 THEN '0-10'
        WHEN cost > 10 AND cost <= 25 THEN '10 < Price <= 25'
        WHEN cost >= 25 and cost <= 100 THEN '25 < Price <= 100'
        ELSE 'Price > 100' end AS price_group
    FROM mmc..product p
    ),
quarters_grouped AS (
    SELECT
    uniqueid,
    unitprice,
    quantity,
    cart_orderdate,
    case WHEN c.cart_orderdate >= DATEADD(QUARTER, -1, getdate()) THEN 'Q1'
    WHEN c.cart_orderdate >= DATEADD(QUARTER, -2, getdate()) and c.cart_orderdate < DATEADD(QUARTER, -1, getdate())THEN 'Q2'
    WHEN c.cart_orderdate >= DATEADD(QUARTER, -3, getdate()) and c.cart_orderdate < DATEADD(QUARTER, -2, getdate())THEN 'Q3'
    WHEN c.cart_orderdate >= DATEADD(QUARTER, -4, getdate()) and c.cart_orderdate < DATEADD(QUARTER, -3, getdate())THEN 'Q4'
    WHEN c.cart_orderdate >= DATEADD(QUARTER, -5, getdate()) and c.cart_orderdate < DATEADD(QUARTER, -4, getdate())THEN 'Q5'
    WHEN c.cart_orderdate >= DATEADD(QUARTER, -6, getdate()) and c.cart_orderdate < DATEADD(QUARTER, -5, getdate())THEN 'Q6'
    WHEN c.cart_orderdate >= DATEADD(QUARTER, -7, getdate()) and c.cart_orderdate < DATEADD(QUARTER, -6, getdate())THEN 'Q7'
    WHEN c.cart_orderdate >= DATEADD(QUARTER, -8, getdate()) and c.cart_orderdate < DATEADD(QUARTER, -7, getdate())THEN 'Q8'
    end AS quarters
    FROM omc..cart c
    WHERE c.cart_orderdate > '2018-01-01'
    ),
sum_by_quarter AS (
    SELECT pg.uniqueid, price_group, quarters, SUM(unitprice * quantity) AS total_sold
    FROM product_grouped pg
    INNER JOIN quarters_grouped qg
        ON pg.uniqueid = qg.uniqueid
    GROUP BY pg.uniqueid, price_group, quarters
),
partition_five AS (
    SELECT quarters, price_group, uniqueid, total_sold, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY  quarters, price_group ORDER BY total_sold DESC) AS RowNo
    FROM sum_by_quarter
    )

SELECT *
FROM partition_five
WHERE RowNo <= 5
ORDER BY  quarters, price_group, total_sold desc
```

I want to know the top 5 selling product ids for products in different price ranges for the last 8 quarters. Where top selling is defined as `unitprice * quantity` from the cart table. The price ranges are `Cost <= $10, 10 < Cost <= 25, 25 < Cost <= 100,  Cost < 100`. My query gives me what I want, but is there an easier way to do this without all the case statements?

Comment: I changed the database tag to sql-server, because the code is obviously for SQL Server.  Please tag with the appropriate database.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider calculating quarter difference from date difference.

```
'Q' + CONVERT(VARCHAR(5), CEILING(DATEDIFF(day, c.cart_orderdate, getdate()) / 91) + 1)
```

Specifically within the *quarters_grouped* CTE:

```
...
quarters_grouped AS (
    SELECT
          uniqueid,
          unitprice,
          quantity,
          cart_orderdate,
          'Q' + CONVERT(VARCHAR(5), CEILING(DATEDIFF(day, c.cart_orderdate, getdate()) / 91) + 1) AS quarters
    FROM omc..cart c
    WHERE c.cart_orderdate > '2018-01-01'
),
...
```

[**Rextester Demo**](https://rextester.com/ZXNF74099) *(with random dates)*